# If two opposite charges are placed next to each other and a field line leaves from one, at what angle does it reach the other one?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

> Two charges $+q_1$ and $-q_2$ are placed at A and B respectively, A line of force emerges from $q_1$ at angle $\alpha$ with line AB. At what angle will it terminate at $-q_2$?
>
> [image]

My approach: Since no of field lines originating or terminating at a charge is proportional to its charge itself, I have assumed the charges to be spherical, therefore no of lines emerging from $q_1$ is $2π/\alpha$ and no of field lines terminating on $-q_2$ is $2π/\beta$ (I have assumed $\beta$ to be the angle) dividing them and equating with the ratio of charges gives me $\beta=\frac{\alpha q_1}{q_2}$.

However, the answer is given as $$\sin^{-1}{\left[\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{q_]}}{\sqrt{q_2}}}\right]}$$

Can anyone explain how have they obtained this answer and find the anomaly in my thinking?

Comment: Here you need to convince yourself that all the field lines emerging from q1 within a cone of Apex angle $\alpha$ that would go to q2 would reside within a cone of Apex angle $\beta$at q2. After this, just equate the flux through the two cones, which is proportional to charge times the solid angle of the cone.

Comment: Please read carefully the site's [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation. As currently written, you're mostly just asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: In particular, your solution has nothing to do with the actual definition of field lines. Field lines follow the *total* electric field, formed by adding the individual fields from all of the charges. You seem to be taking the field from the left-hand charge on the left and a completely different field on the right.

Comment: Your use of "no" would be less confusing if it were replaced by "number".

Comment: The given answer does not meet the requirement that the two angles should be equal if the two charges have the same magnitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the following figure we can conclude that the net flux of $+q_1$ through the area $S$ will be equal to the magnitude of flux of $-q_2$ through that cross section. In essence all the field lines originating from $+q_1$ and passing through the cross section $S$ will converge only on $-q_2$.
[image]

From the concept of solid angle one could say that the ratio of total flux of $+q_1$ to that of it's flux through $S$ will be same as the ratio of total solid angle to that of $S$. Mathematically,
$$\frac{q_1/\epsilon_o}{\phi_1} = \frac{4\pi}{2\pi(1-\cos\alpha)}$$
Similarly for $q_2$:
$$\frac{q_2/\epsilon_o}{\phi_2} = \frac{4\pi}{2\pi(1-\cos\theta)}$$
Equating $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ and applying appropriate trigonometry formulae you get:
$$\theta = 2\sin^{-1}[\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\sqrt{\frac{q_1}{q_2}}]$$
**Note** that, I considered only magnitudes of $q_1$ and $q_2$ throughout.

Comment: I'm thinking that if $q_2$ = - $q_1$, then the angles should be equal. Why the divisor of 2?

Comment: @R.W.Bird Ohh yes I forgot to put that 2 before $\sin^{-1}$.

Comment: @ShriomKumarSingh I think the answer you have given is wrong. I encourage you to check it once again.

Comment: Could you please explain how you got your expression for the solid angle through S.  I would have used π $sin^2$α (area at S / $r^2$).

Comment: In your first two equations, you seem to be saying that the flux through S over the total flux equals the total solid angle over the solid angle through S. One side needs to be inverted.

Comment: @R.W.Bird For the solid angle formula, try seeing this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfmEPHSQ-pA

Comment: Thanks.  I was using a flat surface instead of a spherical surface.